# duplicate link to flag a question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

When flagging a question to close, these are the reasons provided:

[image]

When selecting "it should be closed for another reason", these are the reasons we then get:

[image]

So again a duplicate close reason, a duplicate of a duplicate close reason.

Comment: @Ramhound really? happens to me every time. Open up any post, [say this](http://superuser.com/questions/729996/can-i-export-a-png-image-with-transparent-background-to-emf-and-maintain-the-tra), click Flag, note the duplicate text, click "It should be closed for another reason", note the duplicate text again. Or do you see some other behavior?

Comment: Close is not available at my reputation level.

Comment: Primarily, this is because the "it should be closed for another reason" option just opens the usual *close* dialog (which, obviously, has to contain an option to close as duplicate). The superfluous duplicate option is therefore in the first page of the flagging dialog, which in return is just the remains of the closing changes a while ago, when duplicates were the first closure type to get a new system.

Comment: I was also going to ask this question, but didn't as I didn't want to post a "duplicate duplicate [duplicate]"...